# What do each of connection warning icons mean?

Tags: battlefield-4

[image: performance icons]

Battlefield 4 spring patch of 2015 introduced performance quality icons. I know that color depends on severity of degradation, but what does each of the icons exactly mean?

Comment: The monitor should be general PC performance as in CPU load, the one with the filmstrips probably FPS, the front one is probably bandwidth, while the clock could mean latency. Just a guess though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From left to right:

Server Performance | Packet Loss | High Latency | Latency Variation | Low FPS | Refresh Rate

[image]

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/3j7t3b/the_new_warning_icons/)

Comment: From the [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/3j7t3b/the_new_warning_icons/cunft7z):
What does refresh rate warn about? - _vesko18_

|

It will warn you if the server is running at a tickrate higher than your monitor refresh rate. Most monitors run at 60hz. But BF4 supports all the way up to 144hz for both the game and server. - _1stMora_